# Necessity to backup Cassandra system keyspaces

Tags: backup, restore, cassandra

I was wondering about the necessity to backup (in order to restore of course) the system keyspaces of Cassandra.

My backup/restore procedure is the following:

- backup: snapshots (nodetool) + dump of keyspaces (cqlsh DESC keyspace) on all cluster nodes
- restore:

  - create keyspaces (cqlsh)
  - restore schema.cql of all tables of all snapshots (cqlsh)
  - import tables of all snapshots (sstableloader)

With this procedure, I was wondering:

1. I read that among system keyspaces, only system_schema could be usefull to be backuped/restored, are there others ?
2. Since I recreate keyspaces, and reimport tables schema (cql included in snapshots for each table), is the backup/restore of the keyspace **system_schema** necessary ?

Thank you